# How to get shadows with entities created programmatically in RealityKit?

Tags: realitykit

I've created a series of boxes in code. There is a subtle ambient occlusion where it meets the table but I'm not getting any shadows - either ground shadows or shadows cast on the model itself. I do get ground shadows when I use a model from Reality Composer.

[image: Screenshot]

```swift
let config = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
config.planeDetection = [.horizontal]
session.run(config, options: [])

let anchorEntity = AnchorEntity(plane: .horizontal)
scene.addAnchor(anchorEntity)

var material = PhysicallyBasedMaterial()
material.baseColor = PhysicallyBasedMaterial.BaseColor(tint: .white)

let box1 = ModelEntity(mesh: .generateBox(size: [0.05, 0.03, 0.05]), materials: [material])
box1.position = [0, 0.015, 0]
anchorEntity.addChild(box1)

let box2 = ModelEntity(mesh: .generateBox(size: [0.15, 0.03, 0.05]), materials: [material])
box2.position = [0.05, 0.045, 0]
anchorEntity.addChild(box2)

let box3 = ModelEntity(mesh: .generateBox(size: [0.01, 0.05, 0.01]), materials: [material])
box3.position = [0, 0.085, 0]
anchorEntity.addChild(box3)
```

iOS: 16.1.1